# Drupal Logintoboggan module not sending verification emails to new registrations?

Tags: php, email, drupal, drupal-7, email-verification

so by default *logintoboggan* module should send "one time verification" link emails to newly registered users to validate their emails.
But its not happening ,

settings on page /admin/config/system/logintoboggin

- allow users to login their email - **Enabled**
- use two emails - **Disabled**
- set password - **Unchecked**
- non authenticated role - *i have my own*

settings on page /admin/config/people/accounts

- who can register - **visitors**
- require email verification - **checked**

*welcome(no approval required)* and *welcome(user created by admin*) under emails has [user:validate-url] token .

Moreover, if there is any other method to verify email on drupal-7  please tell.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In admin/config/people/accounts there is a checkbox :  Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account. Maybe that's enough for you.

Comment: no that's not working either. that check-box is locked by logintoboggan and if we enable set password(mentioned above) then it locks require e-mail verification to Unchecked and if disabled , it locks the same to checked.